# Is it bad practice to use a function in an if statement?

Tags: vb.net, function, if-statement

I have a function in another class file that gets information about the battery. In a form I have the following code:

```
If BatteryClass.getStatus_Battery_Charging = True Then
```

It appears Visual Studio accepts this. However, would it be better if I used the following code, which also works:

```
dim val as boolean = BatteryClass.getStatus_Battery_Charging
If val = True Then
```

Is there a difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking in general is which approach is idiomatic.

The technical rule is not to invoke a method multiple times - unless you're specifically checking a volatile value for change - when its result can be preserved in a locally scoped variable. That's not what your asking but its important to understand that multiple calls should typically be bound to a variable.

That being said its better to produce less lines of code from a maintenance perspective as long as doing so improves the readability of your code. If you do have to declare a locally scoped variable to hold the return value of a method make sure to give the variable a meaningful name.

Prefer this [idiomatic VB.NET] one liner:

```
If BatteryClass.getStatus_Battery_Charging Then
```

over this:

```
Dim isBatteryCharging As Boolean = BatteryClass.getStatus_Battery_Charging
If isBatteryCharging Then
```

Another point you should concern yourself with are methods, which when invoked, create a side effect that affects the state of your program. In most circumstances it is undesirable to have a side effect causing method invoked multiple times - when possible rewrite such side affecting methods so that they do not cause any side effects. To limit the number of times a side effect will occur use the same local variable scoping rule instead of performing multiple invocations of the method.

Answer (score 4):

No real difference.

The second is better if you need the value again of course.  It's also marginally easier to debug when you have a value stored in a variable.

Personally I tend to use the first because I'm an old school C programmer at heart!